# Build a Queue without using Collection

Tags: c#

I want to build a queue without using Collection. I just want to write a simple queue as follows:

```
    public class Node{
        public Node prev, next;
        public object data;
    }

    public class Queue
    {
        public Node rear, front;

        public bool IsEmpty(){
            return rear==null || front==null;
        }

        public void Enqueue(object ele){
            Node n = new Node();
            n.data = ele;
            if(rear==null){
                rear = n;
                front = n;
            }else{
                n.next = rear;
                rear = n;
            }
        }

        public Node Dequeue(){
            if(front==null)
                return null;
            Node d = front;
            front = front.prev;
            return d;
        }
    }
```

Adding elements to the queue looks OK. But when I pop an element from the queue. It looks wrong.

Comment: Is this for some assignment? There's no reason otherwise to not use a battle tested BCL type here.

Comment: You never assign anything to `prev`

Comment: You are mishandling `prev` and `next` references. Draw it on paper and see where `prev` and `next` are pointing. Plus, for a queue, you don't need two references (doubly-linked list), one reference is just enough (single-linked list).

Comment: You can remove `Node.Next` and `Queue.rear`. This simplify the code and you will see the problem.

Comment: If this is for an assignment and you don't want to use the built-in queue collection, you could try using the linkedlist collection. When you have it working you can substitute it with your own implementation. Otherwise just use the built-in queue object.

Comment: NO USE ANY COLLECTION!

Comment: I assume you mean "an existing built in collection"? Since the queue you are building *is* a collection.

Comment: The assignment also states not to use generics? Because using object instead of a generic type seems a bit too much old school...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing up prev and next references. For more background info look up linked lists (double and single linked lists).

```
public class Queue
{
    public Node rear, front;

    public bool IsEmpty(){
        return rear==null && front==null;
    }

    public void Enqueue(object ele){
        Node n = new Node();
        n.data = ele;
        if(rear==null){
            rear = n;
            front = n;
        }else{
            rear.next = n;
            n.prev = rear;
            rear = n;
        }
    }

    public Node Dequeue(){
        if(front==null)
            return null;
        Node d = front;
        front = front.next;
        
        if (front == null) {
            rear = null;
        }
        else {
            front.prev = null;
        }
            
        return d;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you've written is approaching a double-linked list but for a typical queue all you need is to know what is at the front and how to queue something at the back (which is where, I think, your confusion with `rear` came from).

You can do this with just one link to the `next` like below:

```
public class Node{
    public Node next;
    public object data;
}

public class Queue
{
    public Node front;

    public bool IsEmpty(){
        return front==null;
    }

    public void Enqueue(object ele){
        Node n = new Node();
        n.data = ele;
        if(front==null){
            front = n;
        }else{
            var f = front;          
            while(f.next != null)
                f = f.next; 
            f.next = n;
        }
    }

    public Node Dequeue(){
        if(front==null)
            return null;
        Node d = front;
        front = front.next;
        return d;
    }
}
```

Live example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/fhKTug